# facebook sdk unity no show hash

Tags: unity-game-engine, facebook-android-sdk

hello i'm trying to set up facebook sdk android but the hash is not displayed I installed openssl but it still doesn't work does anyone know how to fix it? unity 2019.2.11f1

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's complaining about the `keytool` program from the Java JRE or JDK. Make sure you have it somewhere and the directory is in your path. You can see how they look for it here: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-sdk-for-unity/blob/9389c5cfcaf1daa2a49fac39570e51b4563f37be/Facebook.Unity.Editor/android/FacebookAndroidUtil.cs

Comment: Thanks. SOLVED i'm download jdk and install. SOLVED problem